# imu_um6 Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch imu_um6 I get the following return activity (see below). I found the document (http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/imu_um6/html/driver_8py_source.html) that shows:

> ```
> 00045     CMD_BAD_CHECKSUM     = 0xFD # sent by UM6 when it receives corrupted pkt
> ```

I looked at the list of expected settings:

> ```
> 00009     NOTE: this driver expects a number of things to be true:
> 00010     1. Broadcast mode is enabled
> 00011     2. QUATERNION output is enabled
> 00012     2. EULER output is enabled
> 00013     2. ANGULAR VELOCITY output is enabled
> 00014     2. LINEAR ACCEL output is enabled
> ```

But I can't find Angular Velocity or Linear Accel to verify/change setting to see if this may be the issue.

What do I need to do to find these missing settings, and what else do I need to try to eliminate the BAD CHECKSUM error?

> ```
> srv1bf537@ubuntu:~$ source ~/imu_drivers/setup.bash
> >     srv1bf537@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch imu_um6 test.launch
> ... logging to /home/srv1bf537/.ros/log/808547c6-e429-11e1-a5c4-002710017b98/roslaunch-ubuntu-6629.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
> Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:54444/
>
>
> SUMMARY
> ========
>
> PARAMETERS
>  * /imu_um6_node/port
>  * /rosdistro
>  * /rosversion
>
> NODES
>   /
>     imu_pose (imu_um6/imu_pose.py)
>     imu_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     imu_um6_node (imu_um6/imu_um6_node.py)
>     rviz (rviz/rviz)
>
> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid [6645]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> setting /run_id to 808547c6-e429-11e1-a5c4-002710017b98
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6658]
> started core service [/rosout]
> process[imu_um6_node-2]: started with pid [6670]
> process[imu_tf-3]: started with pid [6671]
> process[imu_pose-4]: started with pid [6683]
> process[rviz-5]: started with pid [6684]
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1344740270.811852] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1344740270.843230] Zero Gyros: True
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1344740270.843485] Reset EKF: True
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1344740270.843704] Set Magnetometer Reference: True
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1344740270.843923] Set Accelerometer Reference: True
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> Read Pkt: BAD CHECKSUM
> ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41196/imu_um6-read-pkt:-bad-checksum/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-08-12**:
Have you successfully connected to it with their Windows program?

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2012-08-14**:
Yes, all works fine under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is definitely a compatibility issue of the imu_um6 ros package with the latest firmware (UM2B) for the CH Robotics UM6 IMU.

In order to clear the BAD CHECKSUM error (there are actually two) there are two settings that are different in the UM2B firmware that must be changed.

Under Communication (using the CH Robotics Interface to set the UM6)

Raw Gyro Output needs to be disabled
Temperature Output needs to be disabled

As per the the tutorial on setting up the imu_um6 you must also enable Quaternion Output (under the Communication Tab, same as above), but this is to get the tf to display and has nothing to do with the BAD CHECKSUM message.

Be sure to do a RAM Commit and then a FLASH Commit to get the new settings fully set in the UM6 (again, using the CH Robotics Interface).

---

Originally posted by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) with karma: 160 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1